# How can I change the default colors of the density in gghistogram() in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to update the default colors of my ggplot2 plots in R to

```
seablue <-rgb(0,0.6,0.82)
lightred <-rgb(0.8,0,0)
```

where **seablue** should be the color of the first line and **lightred** should be the color of the second line.

Using

```
update_geom_defaults("line", list(size = 1.75, colour = seablue))
```

the color of the first line is changed to **seablue** for `autoplot()` line graphs.

However, the colors of the density lines in `gghistogram(data, add.normal = T, add.kde = T)` remain unchanged (first: lightblue and second: orange).

How can I change the default colors of the density in `gghistogram()` from the package `forecast`such that the normal density is **seablue** and the kde density is **lightred**?

Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

Related to this, how can I change the second default color of the `autoplot()` line graphs to **lightred**?

(Note: I don't want to change the colors just for one plot, but for all plots of my file.)

Comment: There's a good amount of detail that we'll need to see for this to be a [mcve], such as code, data, packages used, some sort of output, etc. I'm not sure where `gghistogram` comes from, but it's probably not the same as a line. Setting the default for "line" applies to calls to `geom_line`, not just any layers with lines or curves in them.

Comment: It took me a while to realize that my `gghistogram` is from the `forecast` package, and not from the `ggpubr` package. In the `ggpubr` package you can change the Colors at least manually, in the ´forecast` package I couldnt find even that option in the documentation… Does someone have an idea how its still done?